# error data in loop foreach does'nt display good syntax

Tags: php

I don't understand why in my `foreach` loop I can't use
`$products_option_value['products_option_value_id']` for example. I must use 
    `$option['products_option_value']['products_option_value_id']` to display the good result else I have just a value

Below the elements

```
var_dump($options_array);
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '213' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=13)
          'products_option_value_id' => string '171' (length=3)
          'option_value_id' => string '179' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'S' (length=1)
          'image' => null
          'quantity' => string '100' (length=3)
          'subtract' => string '0' (length=1)
          'price' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
          'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
          'weight' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          'weight_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
          'customers_group_id' => string '99' (length=2)
          'products_option_model' => string '99' (length=2)
          'option_tax_class_id' => string '99' (length=2)
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
etc


  foreach ($options_array as $option) {
    foreach ($option['products_option_value'] as $products_option_value) {
      var_dump($products_option_value);
    }
  }
```

the result is :

```
   var_dump($option); result

    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '213' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=13)
          'products_option_value_id' => string '171' (length=3)
          'option_value_id' => string '179' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'S' (length=1)
          'image' => null
          'quantity' => string '100' (length=3)
          'subtract' => string '0' (length=1)
          'price' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
          'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
          'weight' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          'weight_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
          'customers_group_id' => string '99' (length=2)
          'products_option_model' => string '99' (length=2)
          'option_tax_class_id' => string '99' (length=2)
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null

var_dump($products_option_value) result

    products_info_options_new.php:84:string '171' (length=3)
    products_info_options_new.php:84:string '179' (length=3)
    products_info_options_new.php:84:string 'S' (length=1
    etc
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

You should use `foreach($array as $key => $value)` when iterating trough arrays that have keys. (I mean arrays such as this: `array("key" => $value)`, and this is also your array)

Comment: I hope this is what you were asking for. If not then just add a comment here and I will try to improve my answer.

Comment: @J K, note that `$products_option_value` is also a variable, since it is used in the inner `foreach` in the OP's code.

Comment: @J K I inserted $products_option_value[] before the loop, but does'nt work.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder yeah, you are right, I haven't read this question carefully :( Now answer improved

Comment: @Kathy yeah, there isn't $products_option_value variable outside array. Check if the current answer is correct for you.

Comment: @JK sorry maybe my knowledge are not enough, How do you write the loop. I tried different way including foreach($array as $key => $value), i have the same thing. Tk for your help